Extending a curve in pine script
I have done a linear regression on Kaspa (a crypto) and found that it's following a power law .
I calculated the trendline which is a power law in the form of price = a(time)^b
I created a simple tradingview indicator but I just can plot this curve to the last bar of the chart and extending the same curve seems to be impossible for me .
any help?

//@version=5
indicator(title='Kaspa Power Law Bands', shorttitle='KAS Power Law', overlay=true)

// Days X-Axis Value

start = time == timestamp(2022, 06, 01, 0, 0)  // 
days = request.security('CRYPTO:KASUSD', 'D', ta.barssince(start)) 
offset = 205  // days since genesis
d = days + offset

// Power Law Center Line (Regression )

y = math.pow(10, -13.39)*math.pow(d, 4.2654)

// Plot Center, Resistance and Support Lines

p1 = plot(y, title='Center', color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=2)



I searched a lot but I couldn't extend the curve.
I would like to extend this curve to some time in the future for example 5 or 10 years.
the formula is price=(10^-13.39)(d^4.2654)

any updates by anyone?

I can't help you with the mathematical formula, but try to extend a line, from the last 10 periods.
var line lineExtend = na
if barstate.islast
    lineExtend := line.new(
      x1     = bar_index[10],
      y1     = y[10],
      x2     = bar_index,
      y2     = y,
      xloc   = xloc.bar_index,
      extend = extend.right,
      color  = color.new(color.gray, 0),
      width  = 2)
    line.delete(lineExtend[1])



Thanks for your answer , but this is not what I wanted. You simply extended a line . but I need to extend a curve , the exact curve in the picture
